# Remove space in xml element name

Tags: c#, xml

I have some badly formed xml which contains a space in the element name and therefore invalidates the xml when I trying to use it. How can I remove the space using C#? In the example below I want to change  to

Example

```
<Root>
    <Test Element>
    </Test Element>
</Root>
```

Comment: It's not really an answer to your problem, but where the hell do you get such abomination of an XML file from?

Comment: Agreed if you are generating the XML yourself, or with code in your organisation, I would suggest fixing it at that point it's created rather than afterwards.

Comment: Unfortunately the xml is pre-existing and I’m having to manipulate it the way it is but yes it should be fixed. However I'm using XmlSerializer to serialize the xml to an object. Is there anyway to fix the xml before I pass it to the XmlSerializer process. Can I rename the element? I dont want to use string replace or regex.

Comment: @User1334589, basically any XML parser/reader will have trouble with the "XML" you have. If you are forced to 'eat' such a bad "XML", your best and easiest chance is to clean it up using string/regex replacements before feeding it into the XML processor. With such a severe violation of XML, you won't get a solution that is as easy and cheap as a 'free lunch', unfortunately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

`String.Replace(" ", "");`

Replaces white space with no space

Comment: Works only with string arguments, not with char. There is nothing like an empty char. Do it like .Replace(" ", "")

Comment: Used Regex replace to fix the bad xml and now works fine when used with XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++'s TextFX and XML Tools plug-ins can do this and much more. You may sometime need to write clever search terms while you edit in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).